How to publish maven library into GitHub Actions locally?
I have a GitHub Actions script to build an Android app, but I need to include specific prebuilt libraries (ktmidi and rtmidi) that I prebuilt on my local machine before starting work on the project. How can I publish these libraries to ensure the Android app builds correctly?
My GitHub Actions code:
...
jobs:
  build_android:
    name: Assemble android release, send it into App Distribution and notify other team
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: recursive

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config libasound2-dev libjack-jackd2-dev cmake ninja-build doxygen

      - name: Grant Permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Initialize and Update Git Submodules
        run: git submodule update --init --recursive

      - name: Assemble Release
        run: ./gradlew assembleRelease ...

Old version:
jobs:
  build_android:
    name: Assemble android release, send it into App Distribution and notify other team
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: recursive

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config libasound2-dev libjack-jackd2-dev cmake ninja-build doxygen
      - name: Setup NDK Workaround
        run: sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk && sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk

      - name: Build and Publish ktmidi to Local Maven
        run: |
         ls -l ktmidi/
         sed -i "s/signing {}/signing { sign(publishing.publications) }/" ktmidi/build.gradle.kts
         sed -i "s/signing {}/signing { sign(publishing.publications) }/" ktmidi-jvm-desktop/build.gradle
         sed -i "s/signing {}/signing { sign(publishing.publications) }/" ktmidi-native-ext/build.gradle.kts
         ./build-rtmidi.sh
         ./gradlew --warning-mode all build publishToMavenLocal
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_PAT }}
          OSSRH_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_USERNAME }}
          OSSRH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_PASSWORD }}
          SIGNING_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_ID }}
          SIGNING_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_PASSWORD }}
          SIGNING_SECRET_KEY_RING_FILE: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_SECRET_KEY_RING_FILE }}

I add download RtMidi 4.0.0 task to publish this library locally, but I get issue: 'rtmidi/rtmidi_c.h' file not found.

How did you prebuild those libraries locally? Are the command lines configured on the $PATH?

@GuiFalourd, I download ktmidi repo from Github and launch assemble Gradle task, which add some files into .m2 folder on my PC locally

Ok. Does this gradlew publishToMavenLocal command line perform this launch assemble Gradle task operation? Or is it done differently when executed locally?

@GuiFalourd, yes it is. Just perform this launch assemble Gradle task operation

I checked the ktmidi repository to understand how this command might work, and didn't find many things there. However, they seem to be using this publishToMavenLocal command differently in their github workflows, it might be worth trying reproducing the same logic.

@GuiFalourd, thanks!

I'm the ktmidi developer. Since you seem to have "downloaded" the repository content from GitHub, it would not contain those git submodules.
There are some dependencies under external directory, and if your checkout directory there is empty, then you need to get the submodules too.
I would recommend to "clone" the git repository (git clone [the-ktmidi-repo-url]), and run git submodule update --init --recursive to make sure that they are checked out as well.

I get two errors with updated script:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared:releaseCompileClasspath'
`> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':androidApp:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.

Could not find dev.atsushieno:ktmidi:0.6.1.`


I placed my updated script in question

Can you please provide some changes that I need to apply to my GitHub Actions script to make it work?

Your error implies that there is mismatch between the files that your version of Gradle (or whatever) expects and the files that my package actually supplies (Kotlin Multiplatform is kind of moving target). I can only suggest to use the latest 0.8.2 instead. Even if there is any problem in 0.6.1 I cannot provide any fix for that version.

Also, I just noticed that you are trying to build Android app. ktmidi-android does not use RtMidi at all, so unless you also target Kotlin Native or JVM desktop, any attempt to build it would not give any better outcome for you.
